# What's the equivalent idiomatic English expression for "verba volant, scripta manent"?

Tags: idiom-requests, translation, latin

The Latin proverb *[Verba volant, scripta manent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verba_volant,_scripta_manent)* which literally it means "spoken words fly away, written words remain" is quite commonly used in Italian.

> This phrase seems to come from a speech of Caius Titus of the Roman Senate, who suggests that spoken words might easily be forgotten, but written documents can always be conclusive in public matters.
>
> A related, more common,   meaning is that if two people want to establish a formal agreement about something, it is better to put it in writing, rather than just having an oral agreement.

(Wikipedia)

The proverb doesn't necessarily suggest mistrust between the parties involved, but that clarity and points that have been discussed and could be forgotten or misunderstood after some time need to be fixed.

I recently used the proverb during a business conversation in English but I realized I was not understood so I had to explain it. I later checked and saw that it actually is not commonly used in English according to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=verba%20volant&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cverba%20volant%3B%2Cc0).

A usage example could be:

> - "I suggest we write down our agreement as soon as possible, you know…*verba volant*."

Is there a common equivalent proverb or other idiomatic expressions in English to suggest the meaning stated above?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything more colourful than "always get it in writing", which may be more of an adage than an idiom.

Comment: @Spagirl - nice suggestion, sounds like a wise recommendation: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=always+get+it+in+writing&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calways%20get%20it%20in%20writing%3B%2Cc0

Comment: The Latin proverb about words flying away seems quite neutral, as if you may both simply forget what you agreed. I imagine you don't want to suggest that you don't entirely trust  the other party; and that, in fact, you don't entirely trust him.  I would say " I suggest we write it down, just to make sure we're both on the same page."  -

Comment: @davidlol - well, both party will benefit from a written agreement compared to a spoken one.

Comment: Maybe someone from the medical profession can verify - I've heard that "if it isn't written down, it didn't happen" is a mantra in many hospitals, reminding staff to carefully document everything.

Answer (score 7):

This concept is often expressed in English by the phrase:

> A verbal agreement isn't worth the paper it's written on.

It is attributed to Samuel Goldwyn, the Polish American film producer and wit, after he had promised a role to an actress.

Another version is

> An oral contract isn't worth the paper it's written on.

This is sometimes called  [Goldwyn's Law](http://www.sanjeev.net/murphys-laws/goldwyns-law-of-contracts.html).

Comment: Interesting, apparently not a commonly used expression though, and a relatively recent one.https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=A+verbal+agreement+isn%27t%2Can+oral+contract+isn%27t&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CA%20verbal%20agreement%20is%20not%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20oral%20contract%20is%20not%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh  First time I've been on Ngram, I am sure I will owe many hours of pleasure to your introduction.. Doing the search case insensitive and trying the phrase with oral contract, oral agreement, verbal contract and verbal agreement adds up to 0.000 000 6% at the end of the last century, which is close to 'elephant in the room' and 'flying pig'.  Is there a rule of thumb which says a reasonably well educated person should be expected to know expressions with an N gram figure above X?

Answer (score 0):

- Let's *[put it in print](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+in+print)* (before we forget)

> **put something in (to) print**
>   to publish something; to record something spoken in printed letters.

Another idiom, similar to the Italian “[*mettere qualcosa nero su bianco*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/italian-english/mettere-qc-nero-su-bianco)” is

> **[put something down in black and white](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/set+something+down+in+black+and+white)**
>   *Fig. to write down the terms of an agreement; to draw up a written contract; to put the details of something down on paper*.

Comment: Or "put it in writing". https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Put+It+In+Writing

Answer (score 0):

More idiomatically there is: The faintest ink is better than the clearest memory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).