# What's the old saying that means "the written word is more powerful than the spoken"

Tags: popular-refrains

I'm looking for that old saying that means "the written word is more powerful than the spoken"

It suggests that getting an idea on paper and publishing it can reach many more people (because of books, newspapers, magazines etc) than simply saying it one time

Comment: You mean like the pen is mightier than the word?

Comment: @tchrist It’s very similar to that saying, but has a somewhat different meaning.

Comment: It's "The pen is mightier than the **sword**". I think tchrist was making a pun earlier.

Comment: Related: [What's the equivalent idiomatic English expression for “verba volant, scripta manent”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377739/whats-the-equivalent-idiomatic-english-expression-for-verba-volant-scripta-ma)

Comment: @Lawrence in my view the answer to the OP is the maxim first suggested by tchrist, but it does not fit the Latin/English  request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the Latin proverb:

> ***[Verba volant, scripta manent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verba_volant,_scripta_manent)***. Literally translated, it means "spoken words fly away, written words remain".

(Wikipedia)